# How to replace a Jacuzzi bathtub faucet

Tags: plumbing, faucet, bathtub

I have moderate plumbing skills.

What is the procedure for replacing a leaking Jacuzzi bathtub faucet?

Mine is similar to the picture. I DO NOT want to break through the tile to get to the bottom components.

Can this be replaced from above?    Is breaking tile the only option?

[image]

Comment: **Where it is leaking** will determine whether or not if you need to replace it or repair it.

Comment: @Alaska man  Actually it is a drip that i cannot stop.  I've tried tightening the nuts, I've bought new washers.  If I OVER tighten and hold (the cold handle) the drip stops.  But the moment I let go the drip returns.

Comment: Usually  a dripping faucet can be repaired. I believe that faucet has a stem or a cartridge that can be replaced or just a washer on the end of the stem. Sometime the seat that the washer sits into is pitted and that can be honed to function properly.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJKdjLKfEH8  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DX-OLwqFdHI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to replace this from the top.   You have to access it from the side/bottom.  The tub will be glued/screwed in somehow and there will be no way to lift it.  Furthermore, the faucet is most likely soldered into place on rigid copper pipes.  These do not have flexible hoses like a regular bathroom sink faucet.

If there is something wrong with the faucet and it needs repair, feel free to ask another question about that.  Also, you may be able to get a new trim kit for the faucet to make it look newer without replacing the valves.

Comment: Thanks.  To confirm; You believe I would need a plumber to cut and re-solder??

Comment: If you've never done it before, then a plumber would be best.  You would need a bit of soldering experience before trying something in a small area with flammable materials nearby.  Using slip on copper fittings (like sharkbite) normally won't work because of  how these faucets are designed.  I installed one not too long ago and soldering was a hard requirement.  Not trying to discourage you from trying to solder in general, just being honest that this is more of an advanced project.

Answer (score 0):

Is there no access panel built into the design? I know there's a lot of morons and idiots that proliferate the DIY and trades but there SHOULD BE an access panel.

If not then you're SOL and you're going to need to remove the tile located on the side facing you in the picture. There's an odd green blur that's on that panel through so before you start busting tile and grout you should ensure that this entire panel isn't easily removable somehow.

Comment: Picture is from Internet.  But mine is similar.  Access panel is 4' to the left and would be impossible to reach the faucet.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the faucet spout itself just screws on and off without the need to touch any of the plumbing. Last one I did was like this.

Comment: Interesting.  I might turn off the water and try it.  Thanks

Comment: @Marinaio forgot to mention that the new one didn't screw on but instead slipped on and had a small set screw, used an allen wrench, under the water spout at the base that was used to secure it. Hope that makes sense.